# Is $(I+A) A (I+A)^{-1}=A$ if $A$ is psd

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Suppose that $A$ is a positive definite matrix. Is it true that 
\begin{align}
(I+A) A (I+A)^{-1}=A
\end{align}
I tried to use Woodbury identity and got to
\begin{align}
(I+A)( A -A (A^{-1}+I)^{-1})
\end{align}

Comment: Do you mean symmetric positive definite (SPD) or positive definite (PD). Please update your title accordingly. Is the invertibility of $I + A$ part of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(I+A)A=A(I+A)$$

from there, the identity should be obvious.

Comment: More generally, matrices commute with polynomials of themselves.